# “Sertã” é uma palavra usada em português europeu?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-europeu, regionalismo

Encontrei a palavra [***sertã*** (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sert%C3%A3) em português por tentar descobrir a origem da palavra espanhola *sartén* que conhecia pelo menos em português brasileiro como ***frigideira***.

Nunca tinha ouvido *sertã* e fiquei curiosa em saber se a palavra é usada em português de Portugal ou em outras regiões (sejam elas de qualquer parte do mundo onde se tem a língua portuguesa como oficial).

A variação *sartã*, sabem qual a origem desta variação? O priberam indica como regionalismo, mas de onde?

Comment: Em PT-BR nunca ouvi o termo!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Eu cresci e vivi na região de Lisboa, entre Torres Vedras e Setúbal, e aqui foi sempre *frigideira* que ouvi. Que no Porto se diz *sertã* é fácil ver na net. Veja-se este artigo no jornal [Público (2012)](http://p3.publico.pt/node/3368/) sobre uma Susana que se mudou de Cascais, ao pé de Lisboa, para o Porto (grafia original, ênfase minha):

> O sotaque lisboeta ainda se percebe em Susana e as expressões que usa no dia-a-dia (excepção para o fino) são sempre as lisboetas [...] diz cadeado (aloquete), saltos (tacões), atacadores (cordões), ***frigideira (sertã)***, refogado (estrugido), sopra as velas (bufa) e chama gulosos (lambareiros) aos filhos.

Este [Breve dicionário tripeiro-alfacinha](http://lisboalondon.blogspot.pt/2005/07/breve-dicionrio-tripeiro-alfacinha.html) (portuense-lisboeta) “traduz” também *sertã* para *frigideira*, e *sertã* aparece também como termo nortenho neste artigo da [Wikipédia sobre regionalismos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regionalismos_de_Portugal).

Existe também a vila da [Sertã](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sert%C3%A3), perto do centro geográfico de Portugal, e que indiquei no mapa, e uma [lenda](http://asenhoradomonte.com/2014/02/14/2661/), também mencionada no dicionário Houaiss, segundo a qual uma mulher defendeu o castelo da vila atirando aos atacantes uma sertã com azeite a ferver. Este antigo [brazão da vila](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficheiro:Srtoldcrest.jpg) parece celebrar esta lenda. Isto mostra que palavra também já foi usada por ali.

Há vários exemplos destas divisões lexicais entre norte e sul, mas a fronteira varia de caso para caso. Lindley Cintra apresenta no artigo *[Áreas Lexicais no Território Português](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/biblioteca/areas_lexicais.pdf)* oito casos ilustrados em mapas. Por exemplo (mapa 5), diz-se *anho* no noroeste, *cordeiro* numa faixa do nordeste ao litoral centro, e *borrego* mais a sul.

***Sartã*** é uma mera variação de *sertã*. Neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) encontramos as duas formas dos séculos XV ao XVII, mas *sertã* é a mais frequente (13 contra 4 ocorrências).  No Corpus do Português, a partir do século XIX (não há ocorrências no século XVIII) só encontramos *sertã*, mas no Google Books ainda encontramos algumas *sartãs* recentes. Também encontramos as duas formas para o nome da vila.

Esta variabilidade de formas era natural no passado, em que havia pouca comunicação entre regiões. Na aldeia onde cresci, ainda ouvi pessoas mais velhas dizerem *Taresa* e *Sabastião*. E encontramos *Sabastião* no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) até ao século XVII, em menor frequência que *Sebastião*. *Taresa* não encontramos, mas *Tareja*, sim, tal como *Arnesto*. Frequentemente, quando existem duas variantes, uma adquire mais prestígio, e a outra acaba por desaparecer. O que é interessante é que *sartã* tenha sobrevivido até aos dias de hoje.

Comment: Saberia dizer também de onde vem a variação sartã?

Comment: @sumitani Na minha opinião resulta apenas de variação dos sotaques. Normalmente, variação de sotaques não se refletem na grafia. Por exemplo, *peixe* pode ser pronunciado *pêxe, pâixe* e *pêixe*, mas escreve-se sempre *peixe*. No caso de *sertã* persistiram duas grafias. No passado até mesmo o nome da vila aparece grafado *Sertã* e *Sartã*; Vê [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sert%C3%A3#Etimologia).

Comment: @sumitani Nota também que *sartã* é muito menos comum (no Google books, por exemplo), e os dicionários que têm *sartã* simplesmente remetem para *sertã*. Eu sou do sul mas já conhecia *sertã*; *sartã* nunca tinha ouvido.

Comment: Nos anos 50 e 60 morei na Beira Alta, mais especificamente na Guarda, onde ouvia dizer quer a palavra "frigideira" quer "sertã", com larga predominância de "sertã", especialmente nas aldeias, onde era quase exclusivamente. Ainda hoje as pessoas de lá usam este último termo mais frequentemente.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Bate certo com o comentário do Jorge (resposta dele)

Comment: @sumitani Juntei um mapa das sertãs.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, usa-se. Normalmente em meios mais rurais no interior. Em Lisboa em alguns restaurantes também se usa o termo, mas mais numa de dar um tema campestre ou rústico. Segundo uma vizinha minha do interior-centro, ao contrario de uma frigideira uma sertã tem o fundo completamente plano.

- [Sertã](http://interotel.pt/index.php?route=product/product&path=18&product_id=3473)

Comment: Quais meios rurais? No meio rural onde cresci (podem ver [aqui](https://www.google.pt/maps/place/Maxial/@39.1383319,-9.183057,1535m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0xd18cd45b944aa1d:0xa18a6a33ad622afa!8m2!3d39.1385592!4d-9.1770594)) ninguém diz *sertã*.

Comment: Ok. Troca rurais por interior. Na zona da guarda ja ouvi varias vezes a expressão.  Normalmente por malta mais velha e atenção que para ser uma sertã, segundo uma vizinha minha da zona, o fundo da frigideira tem de ser completamente liso de uma ponta a outra imagina uma panela mesmo muito muito baixa e com uma pega em vez de alças.

Comment: Acho que a distribuição é mais norte/sul. Na faculdade, lembro-me de uma pessoa do Porto que dizia sertã. Vários outros exemplos: https://espalhafactos.com/2016/02/06/lisboa-vs-porto-termos/ , https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.327580147280280.75048.327182517320043&type=1 , https://books.google.nl/books?id=499_BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&dq=sert%C3%A3+frigideira+unas&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sert%C3%A3%20frigideira%20unas&f=false

Comment: Pois isso já não sei. Em Lisboa não costumo ouvir, no porto tambem não me recordo de ounvir.

Comment: No Porto não estou habituado a ouvir «frigideira». É muito comprido e complicado de dizer, não faz sentido usar essa palavra queque ;) quando «sertã» serve perfeitamente.